# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in standard audit trigger

Tags: triggers, audit

I have been using a standard block of TSQL for auditing of various tables for some time now. However I now have a problem when running the trigger on a new table: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric". This occurs when running the EXEC (@sql) line. I've determined that the code for @sql is:

```
    insert Audit_AppointmentsWS 
       (Type, 
       TableName, 
       PK, 
       FieldName, 
       OldValue, 
       NewValue, 
       UpdateDate, 
       UserName)

    SELECT 'U',
    'AppointmentsWorkshop',
    +convert(varchar(100),  coalesce(i.UniqueID,d.UniqueID)),
    '[JobHours]',
    convert(varchar(1000),d.[JobHours]),
    convert(varchar(1000),i.[JobHours]),
    '20220816 12:32:43:410',
    'DELLXPS\ian' 
    from #ins i full outer join #del d on i.UniqueID = d.UniqueID where ISNULL(i.JobHours],'') <> ISNULL(d.[JobHours],'')
```

I've tried deleting the trigger & the audit table and then recreating them but no joy. I've also tried copying an existing trigger and just changing the table details but I still get the same error. I'm completely stumped on this and would appreciate some feedback. Many thanks in advance!

Here is the trigger:

```
    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_AppointmentsWS]    Script Date: 16/08/2022 12:02:10 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_AppointmentsWS] ON [dbo].AppointmentsWorkshop FOR UPDATE, DELETE
    AS

    DECLARE @bit INT ,
           @field INT ,
           @maxfield INT ,
           @char INT ,
           @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
           @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
           @AuditTable  VARCHAR(128) ,
           @PKCols VARCHAR(MAX) ,
           @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
           @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
           @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
           @Type CHAR(1) ,
           @PKSelect VARCHAR(MAX)
   
    --Changes required:
    -- 1. Change the name of the trigger and the table, above
    -- 2. Change @TableName to match the table to be audited
    -- 3. Change the @AuditTable to the table holding the changes

    SELECT @TableName  = 'AppointmentsWorkshop'
    SELECT @AuditTable = 'Audit_AppointmentsWS'

    -- date and user
    SELECT @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
   @UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

    -- Action
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
           SELECT @Type = 'U'
      ELSE
           SELECT @Type = 'I'
    ELSE
   SELECT @Type = 'D'

    -- get list of columns
    SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
    SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

    -- Get primary key columns for full outer join
    SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
   FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
   WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
   AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
   AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
   AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    -- Get primary key select for insert
    SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') + '+convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))' 
   FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
   WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
   AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
   AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
   AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME


    IF @PKCols IS NULL
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
      RETURN
    END

    SELECT @field = 0, @maxfield = MAX(COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @Tablename),COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID')) 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

    WHILE @field < @maxfield
    BEGIN
      SELECT @field = MIN(COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @Tablename),COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID')) 
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
           AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @Tablename),COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') > @field
   SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
   SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
   SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
   IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 OR @Type IN ('I','D')
   BEGIN
           SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                   WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                   AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @Tablename),COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') = @field

            SELECT @sql = 'insert ' +  @AuditTable + ' 
            (Type, 
            TableName, 
            PK, 
            FieldName, 
            OldValue, 
            NewValue, 
            UpdateDate, 
            UserName)

            SELECT ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
            + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
            + ',''[' + @fieldname + ']'''
            + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.[' + @fieldname + '])'
            + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.[' + @fieldname + '])'
            + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
            + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
            + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
            + @PKCols
            + ' where ISNULL(i.[' + @fieldname + '],'''') <> ISNULL(d.[' + @fieldname + '],'''')' --Skip identical values and excludes NULLS vs empty strings

           EXEC (@sql)
      END
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally figured it out. The error is being generated with columns of data type 'decimal' and it is down to the ISNULL section of the last SELECT. I've fixed it by checking for the decimal type and then using the following code (which included a zero rather than an empty sting):

```
    + ' where ISNULL(i.[' + @fieldname + '],''0'') <> ISNULL(d.[' + @fieldname + '],''0'')' --Skip identical values and excludes NULLS vs empty strings
```